# How to automatically convert Manual Retain-Release code to ARC?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have thousands of line of code written for iOS 4. The codebase contains many calls to `retain` and `release`, which cause errors when the project is updated to iOS 5 and ARC.

Is there a way to *automatically* convert Manual Retain-Release (MRR) code to Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 6+, the command is now:

`Edit > Convert > To Objective-C ARC...`

Comment: thanks for the update. I mark this as an new answer. Best Regard.. ^_^

Answer (score 13):

From the Xcode 4.2 [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/00200-SW2):

> To initiate the process, enable Continue building after errors in the
>   General Preferences pane, then choose **Edit > Refactor > Convert to
>   Objective-C ARC**. The targets that you convert are updated to build
>   using the Apple LLVM compiler. Xcode attempts to build your target and
>   to determine what changes must be made to use ARC. If it finds any
>   issues that prevent conversion, Xcode displays a dialog directing you
>   to review the errors in the Issue navigator. After you correct the
>   errors, choose the Convert to Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting
>   menu item again to restart the ARC-conversion workflow.

Comment: The errors that are shown are errors such as `ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'` ...