# convert the code to ARC iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have make an code xcode 3.2 and now upgrade my xcode to 4.2 and want to convert my code to use ARC.
Is this possible by xcode to make changes automatically to use ARC.

Comment: As per the [tag:arc] wiki, don't use that tag to refer to automatic reference counting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to automatically change code with ARC enable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874727/how-to-automatically-change-code-with-arc-enable)

Comment: Did you even search before posting this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really an RTFM-type question, but the answer is simple:

Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC