# How to convert iOS 4(Non ARC) project into iOS 5 (Using ARC)

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to automatically change code with ARC enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874727/how-to-automatically-change-code-with-arc-enable)

I am new in iOS development.
I created one project in iOS 4 (Non ARC). I want to converts this project in iOS 5 (with ARC).

Is their any option in Xcode which directly convert my project in iOS 5 (using ARC) ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Edit -> Refactor -> Convert To Objective-C ARC

Comment: I have tried this but It will not replace keyword retain to strong. Should I change the keyword OR is it ok with ARC ?